# Display multiple attributes for one point

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, labeling, symbology, fields-attributes

I am using ArcGIS 10.  How can I display multiple attributes for a single point.  For example, I would like to display (graphically if possible) the amenities provided at various recreational areas... such as my point location "Graham's Landing" and have a symbol for camping, fishing, boat ramp, bathrooms and etc that reference the data in the attribute table.  I would like to do this for each point (rec facility) that I have.

Thanks and I am open to other ideas as well!

Comment: @Allen, You are wanting to show a symbol that potentially depicts the presence of one to many attributes per point, correct?

Comment: See the 9th image down on this site: The Terrarpin Creek image  http://www.alabamascenicrivertrail.com/trip-planner/  I would like to be able to do something like this.

Answer (score 3):

To do this you need to use a combination of a few different layer properties:

- First, create and save your own custom label symbols based on the existing combination of unique characteristics, e.g. see image below!

[image]

- Next, for each of your unique classes you will have to setup up a separate label class based on a SQL Query.  This will reference your various database columns to see if combinations of values exist or not, which you may then associate your custom symbols to.

You may also do this manually in Arc by placing graphics, or exporting your map as an image and making additional cartographic enhancements using a photo editor software (eg. GIMP or Adobe Illustrator..etc).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Let me try this and I will reply later on.

Answer (score 0):

I like @artwork21's idea.

An alternative approach might be to load the featureclass into a map document as a layer as many times as you have fields you wan to symbolize, symbolizing each layer on a different field. Might have to fiddle a little more with the placement properties than w/artwork21's approach, since you'll be relying on ArcMap to do this automagically.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation.  I believe that Roland's idea is a little bit better (depending on the circumstances).

For instance, if you have three classes (A, B, C) and you want to make custom symbols for each permutation of them, you'll have to hand-make a lot of symbols:
A
B
C
AB
AC
BC
ABC

But it might be easier to simply place A at an offset of (-10, 0) and B at an offset of (10,0) and C at an offset of (0, -10).

This will always place each of the three symbols at different locations relative to the point (left, right, and above - those were x,y offsets) and if you simply insert a new layer with a new symbol for each of A, B, and C, then you will have done 1/3 the work.

If you have more attributes than will fit, you're in trouble.  If not, you should be fine.  But both the above ideas are great too.